# How to create an effective Index with this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Currently, this portion of the code runs very slowly (~2 hours).

```
select 
            tf.Brown,
            case when tf.type=2 
                 then case when tf.ColorType='S' THEN 'SE' ELSE 'CD' END
                 else case when tf.ColorType='S' THEN ltrim(rtrim(tf.Yellow))+'S' ELSE tf.Yellow end END as Yellow, 
            tf.baseNumber,
            tf.baseAlpha,
            null,
            null,
            SettlementDate,
            null,
            @Month,
            @Year,
            case 
                when status in ('T','I') and shapeType  in ('R','O','I','D') then 'TXN'
                when status = 'C' then 'CAN'
                when shapeType  in ('R','O','I','D') then 'TXN'
                end as FType,
            case
                when status in ('T','I') and shapeType  in ('R','O','I','D') then 'BT' 
                when shapeType  in ('R','O','I','D')  then 'SET'
                else ''
                end as StatusType,
            tf.ColoPiode,
            null,   
            null,
            null,   
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(PrimeNumber,FactorRate),
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(PrimeNumber,FactorAmount),
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(tf.PrintX,dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(@BrownX,FactorAmount * dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,PrimeNumber,@BrownX,@Month,@Year))* dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,@BrownX,tf.PrintX,@Month,@Year)),
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint('US',dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(@BrownX,FactorAmount * dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,PrimeNumber,@BrownX,@Month,@Year))* dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,@BrownX,'US',@Month,@Year)),
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(cp.X,dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(@BrownX,FactorAmount * dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,PrimeNumber,@BrownX,@Month,@Year))* dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,@BrownX,cp.X,@Month,@Year)),
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(PrimeNumber,
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(PrimeNumber,ln)
            +dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(PrimeNumber,Pi)
            +dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(PrimeNumber,Units)
            ),  
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(tf.PrintX,
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(tf.PrintX,dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(@BrownX,ln * dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,PrimeNumber,@BrownX,@Month,@Year))* dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,@BrownX,tf.PrintX,@Month,@Year))
            +dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(tf.PrintX,dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(@BrownX,Pi * dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,PrimeNumber,@BrownX,@Month,@Year))* dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,@BrownX,tf.PrintX,@Month,@Year))
            +dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(tf.PrintX,dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(@BrownX,Units * dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,PrimeNumber,@BrownX,@Month,@Year))* dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,@BrownX,tf.PrintX,@Month,@Year))
            ),
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint('US',
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint('US',dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(@BrownX,ln * dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,PrimeNumber,@BrownX,@Month,@Year))* dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,@BrownX,'US',@Month,@Year))
            +dbo.GetXDecimalPoint('US',dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(@BrownX,Pi * dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,PrimeNumber,@BrownX,@Month,@Year))* dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,@BrownX,'US',@Month,@Year))
            +dbo.GetXDecimalPoint('US',dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(@BrownX,Units * dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,PrimeNumber,@BrownX,@Month,@Year))* dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,@BrownX,'US',@Month,@Year))
            ),
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(cp.X,
            dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(cp.X,dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(@BrownX,ln * dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,PrimeNumber,@BrownX,@Month,@Year))* dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,@BrownX,cp.X,@Month,@Year))
            +dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(cp.X,dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(@BrownX,Pi * dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,PrimeNumber,@BrownX,@Month,@Year))* dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,@BrownX,cp.X,@Month,@Year))
            +dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(cp.X,dbo.GetXDecimalPoint(@BrownX,Units * dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,PrimeNumber,@BrownX,@Month,@Year))* dbo.fnGetEx(tf.Brown,tf.Yellow,@BrownX,cp.X,@Month,@Year))
            ),
            Quantity,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            SName,
            CR,
            0,
            GetDate()
            ,SType
            ,referenceNumber --transactionRefNo
            ,case WHEN Status NOT IN ('C','F','N','M') and shapeType not IN ('T','B','E') THEN 'OTC'
            WHEN Status = 'C' and shapeType not IN ('T','B','E') THEN 'CANC'
            WHEN Status ='N' THEN 'ON'
            WHEN Status = 'M' THEN 'CANC' END
            ,FactorAmount
            ,ISNULL(sm.IC ,'')
        from TriangleFinal tf (nolock)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Country cp (NOLOCK)
        ON cp.Yellow = tf.Yellow
        LEFT JOIN Maroon sm (NOLOCK)
        ON tf.ColoPiode = sm.ColoPiode
        where tf.Brown=@Brown
        and tf.[Year]=@Year
        and tf.[Month]=@Month
        and tf.type <= case when @Brown='HK' then 3 else 1 end
```

TriangleFinal table: ~900,000 rows (clustered index on Brown, Year, Month)
Country Table:~100 rows
Maroon Table: ~600,000 rows (primary key on ColorCode)

The below is a non-clustered Index that i created, as the table already has a clustered index. I read that fields included should include 'Join's and 'where' parameters.

Hecne, My Index is:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [V1_Index] ON [dbo].[TriangleFinal]
(
    [Year] DESC,
    [Brown] ASC,
    [Month] ASC,
    [type] ASC,
    [Yellow] ASC,
    [ColorCode] ASC

)
INCLUDE ([PrimeNumber],[FactorAmount],[Ln],[Pi],[Units])

WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Since the query gets about ~900,000 rows and takes ~2hours, i have two questions:

1) Is there a better index that will improve this code and does the order of the parameters matter in this case?

2) Should i be looking to optimizing elsewhere?

Comment: I think it's the `Scalar UDF`. What does `GetXDecimalPoint` do? Can you post it?

Comment: And can you post the query execution plan? Some of the issue could also reside in the joins

Comment: you  should take a look at this article about the "missing indexs" feature it could show you what indexes you need on what table to improve performance.  
http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/database/3208-improve-sql-performance-find-your-missing-indexes.html